# Embedded audio conference API

Tags: audio, twilio, webrtc

I really don't have knowledge about this area (WebRTC, video conference, audio conference, etc).

I want to add to my system (web application) a client support using audio conference.

I was looking for Twilio, it seems a good solution, but I think it doesn't fit my case, because it always need a virtual phone number to get works and I don't need it at my system.

What I need is something like Facebook calls, Google Hangouts (without video).

Is there any solution/library/API for it? It's no necessary be a free solution.

Comment: How do you plan to determine who to call without some identifier?

Comment: The system has login, I suppose to make userA calling UserB

Comment: So clients need to log in to have the call support

Comment: Right, so just attach this ID from Twilio to your user data.

Comment: So don't I need a phone number on Twilio? Which Twilio solution should I use? They have so many solutions

Comment: Check out the Twilio Programmable Voice SDK's for Javascript, iOS or Android.  That is a pure VoIP solution, no phone numbers required. https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll check it all for sure